# Transforming full names to surname and initial

Tags: python, strings

I have a large data frame that I want to merge with another dataset. In order to do so I need to get the names of individuals into a certain format. The function below converts the name in 'column' to the desired format (mostly) and stores it in `newColumn`.

My question is, is there a better (faster and/or more pythonic) way to do this?

The main aim is to transform full names into surname and initials, such as:

- Novak Djokovic = Djokovic N.
- Jo-Wilfred Tsonga = Tsonga J.W.
- Victor Estrella Burgos = Estrella Burgos V.
- Juan Martin Del Potro = Del Potro J.M.

```
def convertNames(df,column, newColumn):
    df[newColumn] = 'none'

    for player in df[column]:

        names = player.split(' ')

        if len(names) == 2:

            if (len(names[0].split('-')) > 1):
                newName = names[1]+' '+names[0].split('-')[0][0]+'.'+names[0].split('-')[1][0]+'.'
            else:
                newName = names[1]+' '+names[0][0]+'.'

        elif len(names) == 3:
            newName = names[1]+' '+names[2]+' '+names[0][0]+'.'

        else:
            newName = names[2]+' '+names[3]+' '+names[0][0]+'.'+names[1][0]+'.'

        df[newColumn][df[column] == player] = newName

    return df
```

Comment: Your code doesn’t match your sample output.  The code converts “Victor Estrella Burgos” into “Estrella Burgos V.”, not “Burgos V.E.”  Which represents the desired behaviour: the sample output or the code?

Comment: What about `Alex De Minaur`?

Comment: @AJNeufeld, Sorry, that was me just trying to copy and past everything. You are right. The sample code produces the sample code produces the correct output. I have corrected the question.

Comment: @Stefan, the desired result for Alex De Minaur is De Minaur A.

Comment: Still inconsistent.  Sample code produces “Estrella Burgos V.”, not “Burgos Estrella V.”

Comment: What about `John Patrick Smith`? Any rule converting `Alex De Minaur` to `De Minaur A.` will convert `John Patrick Smith` to `Patrick Smith J.`. Spaniards mostly have two surnames, others mostly one. Any simple approach will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing way too much `split()`-ing.  You split on ‘-‘, and if you find the length of the split is greater than 1, you split on the ‘-‘ twice more, to get the first and the second part of the hyphenated name.  Split once, and save the result in a list, and access the list elements!

You are doing too much in `convertNames()`.  It would be better to create a `convertName()` method, which just processes the player name into the desired form.  Then you could call that method from `convertNames()`.

```
def convertName(player):
    names = player.split(' ')

    if len(names) == 2:
        names[0:1] = names[0].split('-', 1)

    surname = min(len(names)-1, 2)

    return ' '.join(names[surname:]) + ' ' + ''.join(name[0]+'.' for name in names[:surname])

# Test data
for player in ('Novak Djorkovic', 'Jo-Wilferd Tsonga', 'Victor Estrella Burgos', 'Juan Martin Del Potro'):
    print(player, ':', convertName(player))
```